# Paypal IPN: Invalid byte sequence in UTF-8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal, utf-8

I have a ruby app that processes paypal payments. Recently we changed to ruby 2.3.0 and have recently incurred this error: ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8

I've posted the params (cleaned) below and pretty sure it is coming from the Swedish characters and the charset (windows).

I'm not sure exactly how to fix this, or watch out for it in the future.

I'm also not clear on what part of the code the error is occurring.

Help?

```
» 30 Mar 2016 10:58:47.729 2016-03-30 17:58:47.428957+00:00 app web.1 - - Started POST "/en/paypal_ipns/cart_purchase_ipn" for 173.0.81.1 at 2016-03-30 17:58:47 +0000
» 30 Mar 2016 10:58:47.731 2016-03-30 17:58:47.435860+00:00 app web.1 - - Processing by PaypalIpnsController#cart_purchase_ipn as HTML
» 30 Mar 2016 10:58:47.731 2016-03-30 17:58:47.435988+00:00 app web.1 - - Parameters: {"mc_gross"=>"10.15", "protection_eligibility"=>"Eligible", "address_status"=>"confirmed", "payer_id"=>"removed", "address_street"=>"Kung\xE4lvsgatan 6 A", "payment_date"=>"08:07:48 Mar 30, 2016 PDT", "payment_status"=>"Completed", "charset"=>"windows-1252", "address_zip"=>"41669", "first_name"=>"Martin", "mc_fee"=>"0.70", "address_country_code"=>"SE", "address_name"=>"Martin removed", "notify_version"=>"3.8", "custom"=>"7173", "payer_status"=>"verified", "business"=>"removed@gmail.com", "address_country"=>"Sweden", "address_city"=>"G\xF6teborg", "quantity"=>"1", "verify_sign"=>"removed", "payer_email"=>"removed@hotmail.com", "txn_id"=>"removed", "payment_type"=>"instant", "last_name"=>"removed", "address_state"=>"", "receiver_email"=>"removed@gmail.com", "payment_fee"=>"0.70", "receiver_id"=>"removed", "txn_type"=>"web_accept", "item_name"=>"removed", "mc_currency"=>"USD", "item_number"=>"13536", "residence_country"=>"SE", "transaction_subject"=>"", "payment_gross"=>"10.15", "ipn_track_id"=>"removed", "locale"=>"en"}
» 30 Mar 2016 10:58:47.738 2016-03-30 17:58:47.446401+00:00 app web.1 - - Cart Load (2.2ms) SELECT "carts".* FROM "carts" WHERE "carts"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1 [["id", 13536]]
» 30 Mar 2016 10:58:47.738 2016-03-30 17:58:47.478086+00:00 app web.1 - -
» 30 Mar 2016 10:58:47.738 2016-03-30 17:58:47.478097+00:00 app web.1 - -
» 30 Mar 2016 10:58:47.738 2016-03-30 17:58:47.478098+00:00 app web.1 - - Exception caught, but rendered in pretty page
» 30 Mar 2016 10:58:47.738 2016-03-30 17:58:47.478103+00:00 app web.1 - - #<ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8>
» 30 Mar 2016 10:58:47.738 2016-03-30 17:58:47.478272+00:00 app web.1 - - /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:447:in `count'
» 30 Mar 2016 10:58:47.738 2016-03-30 17:58:47.478274+00:00 app web.1 - - /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:447:in `binary?'
» 30 Mar 2016 10:58:47.738 2016-03-30 17:58:47.478275+00:00 app web.1 - - /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:316:in `visit_String'
» 30 Mar 2016 10:58:47.738 2016-03-30 17:58:47.478275+00:00 app web.1 - - /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:163:in `accept'
» 30 Mar 2016 10:58:47.743 2016-03-30 17:58:47.478276+00:00 app web.1 - - /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:493:in `block in visit_hash_subclass'
» 30 Mar 2016 10:58:47.743 2016-03-30 17:58:47.478278+00:00 app web.1 - - /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5.1/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb:185:in `each_pair'
» 30 Mar 2016 10:58:47.743 2016-03-30 17:58:47.478278+00:00 app web.1 - - /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5.1/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb:185:in `each_pair'
» 30 Mar 2016 10:58:47.743 2016-03-30 17:58:47.478279+00:00 app web.1 - - /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:491:in `visit_hash_subclass'
» 30 Mar 2016 10:58:47.743 2016-03-30 17:58:47.478280+00:00 app web.1 - - /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:389:in `visit_Hash'
» 30 Mar 2016 10:58:47.743 2016-03-30 17:58:47.478280+00:00 app web.1 - - /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:163:in `accept'
» 30 Mar 2016 10:58:47.743 2016-03-30 17:58:47.478281+00:00 app web.1 - - /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych/visitors/yaml_tree.rb:127:in `push'
» 30 Mar 2016 10:58:47.748 2016-03-30 17:58:47.478282+00:00 app web.1 - - /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/psych.rb:416:in `dump'
» 30 Mar 2016 10:58:47.748 2016-03-30 17:58:47.478283+00:00 app web.1 - - /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/coders/yaml_column.rb:20:in `dump'
» 30 Mar 2016 10:58:47.748 2016-03-30 17:58:47.478283+00:00 app web.1 - - /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/type/serialized.rb:26:in `type_cast_for_database'
» 30 Mar 2016 10:58:47.748 2016-03-30 17:58:47.478284+00:00 app web.1 - - /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/type/mutable.rb:5:in `type_cast_from_user'
» 30 Mar 2016 10:58:47.748 2016-03-30 17:58:47.478285+00:00 app web.1 - - /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/attribute.rb:110:in `type_cast'
» 30 Mar 2016 10:58:47.748 2016-03-30 17:58:47.478286+00:00 app web.1 - - /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/attribute.rb:42:in `original_value'
» 30 Mar 2016 10:58:47.748 2016-03-30 17:58:47.478286+00:00 app web.1 - - /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/attribute.rb:37:in `value'
» 30 Mar 2016 10:58:47.752 2016-03-30 17:58:47.478287+00:00 app web.1 - - /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/attribute.rb:50:in `changed_from?'
» 30 Mar 2016 10:58:47.752 2016-03-30 17:58:47.478288+00:00 app web.1 - - /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:142:in `_field_changed?'
» 30 Mar 2016 10:58:47.752 2016-03-30 17:58:47.478289+00:00 app web.1 - - /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:115:in `save_changed_attribute'
» 30 Mar 2016 10:58:47.752 2016-03-30 17:58:47.478289+00:00 app web.1 - - /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:98:in `write_attribute'
» 30 Mar 2016 10:58:47.752 2016-03-30 17:58:47.478290+00:00 app web.1 - - /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:50:in `__temp__07162716d637'
» 30 Mar 2016 10:58:47.752 2016-03-30 17:58:47.478291+00:00 app web.1 - - /app/app/models/paypal_ipn.rb:20:in `params_info='
» 30 Mar 2016 10:58:47.752 2016-03-30 17:58:47.478291+00:00 app web.1 - - /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:54:in `public_send'
» 30 Mar 2016 10:58:47.762 2016-03-30 17:58:47.478292+00:00 app web.1 - - /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:54:in `_assign_attribute'
» 30 Mar 2016 10:58:47.762 2016-03-30 17:58:47.478293+00:00 app web.1 - - /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:65:in `block in assign_nested_parameter_attributes'
» 30 Mar 2016 10:58:47.762 2016-03-30 17:58:47.478293+00:00 app web.1 - - /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:65:in `each'
» 30 Mar 2016 10:58:47.762 2016-03-30 17:58:47.478294+00:00 app web.1 - - /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:65:in `assign_nested_parameter_attributes'
» 30 Mar 2016 10:58:47.762 2016-03-30 17:58:47.478295+00:00 app web.1 - - /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:45:in `assign_attributes'
» 30 Mar 2016 10:58:47.762 2016-03-30 17:58:47.485285+00:00 app web.1 - - Rendered main/message.html.haml within layouts/application (1.4ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have strings in there with extended ascii, and they're being interpreted as UTF-8.  You need to force change their encoding to something supporting those high bytes, "ISO-8859-1" would be my recommendation, and then convert to UTF-8 after that:

```
str.force_encoding("ISO-8859-1").encode("UTF-8")
```